# ADF: how to set specific view criteria in Saved Search programmatically in af:query

Tags: java, oracle-adf

As described in the title, when we use the  component in ADF, it will always use the view criteria which is selected in saved search as the filter.

Now the requirement is that, without selecting the view criteria manually from UI, can we set one specific view criteria as the saved search and use it for search and filter?

In below example, we have two view criteria here: BooksViewCriteria and Named Criteria for search. It will use the BooksViewCriteria by default. Now we need to use the Named Criteria but without selecting it from the UI but from code programmatically.

[image]

Any one can provide the code snippet for this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You can queue a `queryEvent.SELECT` (`QueryOperationEvent`) on the component. The QueryDescriptor object that you need to pass should contain the other VC.

1. Please use `queryModel.create()` API to retrieve the right `QueryDescriptor`.
2. Construct the `queryOperationEvent` and queue.
3. Call `queryComponent.reset()` API call.
4. PPR the query panel.

Here you can read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/adf/api-reference-faces/toc.htm) for all the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any need to do it programmatic ? while you can just drag and drop the new created criteria "Named Criteria" on your page.

Comment: Yes I know this is the easiest way to use the criteria. But now the scenario does not allow to select the criteria manually from the dropdown list from UI. That's why I ask this question.